# Laravel belongsToMany retrieve more then one row

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So im creating a booking system where you can create maps and assign them to an event. I have 3 tables to handle this, `events`, `maps`, and `event_maps`

I have after reading the Laravel Documentation i decided to set up a belongsToMany relation.

But when i try to retrieve my maps thru my event model i only get one the first row.

in my controller i do

```
public function displayForm($id)
{
    $event = EventModel::find($id);
    print_r($event->maps);
}
```

The result is a Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object with the last out of 2 maps, and i can't for my life figger out how to get them all.

My EventsModel

```
public function maps()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Booky\MapsModel',
        // Table name of the relationship's joining table.
        'event_maps',
        // Foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship
        'map_id',
        // Foreign key name of the model that you are joining to
        'event_id'
    );
}
```

My MapsModel

```
public function event()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Booky\EventsModel',
        // Table name of the relationship's joining table.
        'event_maps',
        // Foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship
        'event_id',
        // Foreign key name of the model that you are joining to
        'map_id'
    );
}
```

The database looks something like this

```
events
  - id
  - lots of irrelevant data
maps
  - id
  - lots of irrelevant data
event_maps
  - id
  - event_id
  - map_id
```

I was thinking that perhaps i should use another relation type, but as far as i understand they don't use a relation table like `event_maps`.

Everything else work as expected.

Anyone who could clear up this mess? :)

Comment: So, the event should have only 1 map? In this case, the `events` table should have the `map_id` foreign key.

Comment: An Event can have any number of maps, and they can be reused and used by other events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `id`s are inverted in the relation. Try this:

```
public function maps()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Booky\MapsModel',
        // Table name of the relationship's joining table.
        'event_maps',
        // Foreign key name of the model that you are joining to
        'event_id'
        // Foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship
        'map_id',
    );
}
```

And:

```
public function event()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Booky\EventsModel',
        // Table name of the relationship's joining table.
        'event_maps',
        // Foreign key name of the model that you are joining to
        'map_id'
        // Foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship
        'event_id',
    );
}
```

Comment: F me and call me Boby Hill, that solved it. Thanks alot ^^
Goint to read up more on them arguments.

Comment: Glad to know it helps you!! :)